# has error after add pagedList.Mvc package to my project

Tags: model-view-controller, pagedlist

I wanted to add page number with a pagedList.MVC package into my razor view page so I added package and then it's my Controller:

```
        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchPathId, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.IdPercorsoSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "IdPercorso_desc" : "";
        if (searchPathId != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchPathId = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchPathId;

        var listPercorsiModel = from listObj in _context.PercorsiModel
                                                      orderby listObj.IdPercorso
                                                      select listObj;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchPathId))
        {
            //listPercorsiModel = listPercorsiModel.Where(s => s.IdPercorso == (System.Convert.ToInt32(searchPathId))).ToList();
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "IdPercorso_desc":
                listPercorsiModel = listPercorsiModel.OrderByDescending(s => s.IdPercorso);
                break;
                //case "Date":
                //    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                //    break;
                //case "date_desc":
                //    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                //    break;
        }
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        //return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        return View(listPercorsiModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

and then in my view after add this code i had error:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

my error:

[image]

Comment: ok, want to inform that because I used .net core application had a problem and i found another package for paging number and its working perfect: x.pagedlist.mvc.core

Answer (score 0):

ok, want to inform that because I used .net core application had a problem and I found another package for paging number and its working perfect:

x.pagedlist.mvc.core